# How to achieve load more only with php?

Tags: php

I am loading items from backend in php. I have one button. When user clicks on it, first it will load 15 objects, then 30, 45... How to achieve this with php alone?

Comment: Voted to close as it's an off-topic question for SO (_so expect it to be closed_). Keep in mind that "__write/debug-my-code__", "__recommend/search-something-for-me__", "__tutorial__" requests and "__low-effort__", "__unclear__", "__opinion-based__", "**non-programming-related**" questions are [Off-Topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: For your next questions please, go to the [Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) then read  [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask a Question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Can't be done with PHP only, because its going to require HTML for sure. And in the way you've described it, javascript+ajax too since you apparently don't want the whole page reloading.

Answer (score 0):

When button is clicked, it generates http request. So pass to the request how many objects you want to load. You can send to the server how many objects was loaded last time, and on the server return that number + 15.